# App Crashing on start after adding react native firebase in android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-firebase

After adding react-native firebase plugin into my react native app, my app is crashing while launching it.

i'm using 
RN 0.51,
gradle 2.2.3 & 2.14.1

```
dependencies {
compile project(':react-native-config')
compile project(':react-native-code-push')
compile (project(':react-native-camera')) {
    exclude group: "com.android.support"
}
```

compile "com.android.support:exifinterface:26.1.0"

```
compile project(':react-native-beacons-manager')
//compile project(':react-native-google-places')
compile project(':react-native-device-info')
compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

compile project(':react-native-fcm')
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1' //this decides your firebase SDK version
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'

      compile project(':react-native-bluetooth-status')

   compile project(':react-native-beacons-manager')
compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
```

}

These are my plugins i have in my project. in new gradle version all my plugins got obsolete so i downgraded gradle. i tried everything but still my app is crashing and i'm getting the same error. please help me.. thank you

this is my error logs

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.spazebudenterprise, PID: 8089
                                              java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbp;
                                                     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6057)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5628)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5567)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1625)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6339)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:945)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.spazebudenterprise-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.spazebudenterprise-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.spazebudenterprise-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                                                     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
```

Comment: Add more info with some code!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've imported the Google imports into your Gradle plugin and that it's updated ie, version 15.0.0

https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.0.x/installation/android

Project build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}



allprojects {
    repositories {


        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

app build.gradle file

```
dependencies {

    implementation(project(':react-native-firebase')) {
        transitive = false
    }

    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.0") {
        force = true
    }

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

/* add the following to the VERY BOTTOM of your app android/app/build.gradle file */
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

`gradle-wrapper.properties` found under `project_name\android\gradle\wrapper`

```
#Fri Mar 02 12:52:38 IST 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

in the terminal
`cd android` followed by `gradlew clean` or `.\gradlew clean` ( not sure about the slash, it could ne / or \ try both) then `cd ..` and `react-native run-android`

Comment: i've imported it.but i'm using gradle version 2.3, is that a problem?

Comment: @RameshKrishnan I have added some more details, do check it out

Comment: i tried everything but no luck again my app crashes. i recreated my app n install react native fcm it works properly when i add my list of plugins app started crashing again.

Comment: Can you create a repo on github and provide a link so I can check it.

Comment: thanks for ur help.. i've fixed this issue my own, actually the problem with google-places, react-native-camera and react-native device info plugin. i've replaced the react-native-device-info with react-native-device-information plugin and google-places i set the gms version to 11.0.1 and i set the same version to firebse also. it got fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

Finally i resolved the issue.
issue is google services version conflicts between react-native-fcm, react-native-camera, react-native-device-info, react-native-google-places.

i replaced
react-native-camera to react-native-camera-kit,
 react-native-device-info to  react-native-device-information
and i changed the google play services in google-places plugin to

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.+"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.+"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.+"
```